# How to turn a column of lists in pandas to a sparse DataFrame of the unique values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I have for each row id, a list of values as a pandas column.
the structure is as follows:

```
df = {'id1':[['a','b','c','d']],'id2':[['a','d','e','j']],'id3':[['b','d','i','q']]},
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df,orient='index')
```

which gives me:

[image: dataset_example]

At first I've created on the side a set of unique values, using this code:

```
l = df.values.tolist()
flat_set = {item for sublist in l for item in sublist}
```

at the end, I need to get a sparse version of this:

[image]

Notes:

1. no. of unique values in the set - 100K~
2. no. of ids - 60K~

I don't mind keeping a dict on the side if shortening the names of the columns leads to 
reduced memory,
but the unpacking from list, to sparse is the hard part, for me.

Please help :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df[0]),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
print (df)
     a  b  c  d  e  i  j  q
id1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
id2  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
id3  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

EDIT: For sparse DataFrame add `sparse_output=True` to `MultiLabelBinarizer` and use [`DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)
a = mlb.fit_transform(df[0])

df = df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(a, columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
print (df)
     a  b  c  d  e  i  j  q
id1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
id2  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0
id3  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1

print (df.dtypes)
a    Sparse[int32, 0]
b    Sparse[int32, 0]
c    Sparse[int32, 0]
d    Sparse[int32, 0]
e    Sparse[int32, 0]
i    Sparse[int32, 0]
j    Sparse[int32, 0]
q    Sparse[int32, 0]
dtype: object
```

Comment: what do you refer by df[0]?

Comment: @Talis - it is column name `0`, maybe need `df['package']`

Comment: worked, but, can i force it to be sparse upon declaring df?, here: 

df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df[0]),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)

Comment: @Talis - answer was edited.